# How do I write equations on Math.SE?

Tags: support, mathjax, math-se

I have checked the Mathematics Stack Exchange site, and have noticed equation syntax on the questions. Is there a guide or link of how to write these formulas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably, these links might help you.

[LaTex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX)

[LaTeX/Advanced Mathematics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

In the above links, the equations are embedded within `\begin{equation}`  and `\end{equation}`, you just have to replace those with double dollar signs **$$**.

By the way, Math.SE uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which uses LaTeX to formulate equations.

*Screenshot from Math.SE to show some sample equations:*

[image: Math.SE]

---

In the Mathematics [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) / Our Model, there is a pinned link: "[How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)". The page linked there has a brief "Getting Started" guide to MathJax, and a link to the main [MathJax quick reference page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) FAQ (which can load rather slowly because it has a *lot* of MathJax on it).

It also links to a page of [additional pointers and references](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto). The latter page has numerous helpful links, including a link to the very comprehensive [Alphabetical List of TEX Commands available in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm), by Dr Carol Fisher.

The Quantum Computing site has a guide: "[Tutorial: How to use TeX/MathJax to render math notation?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/278)", which expands on Math.meta.SE's "[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/510296)". Similarly, the [Physics Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange) has "[What notation and symbols are commonly used here?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)".

See also this Q&A: "[What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/282094)" for a list of other notational formats supported by Stack Exchange; including a list of MathJax supported sites.

A full list of the sites that support MathJax is also maintained at "[Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)".

However, (currently) not all of those sites have such a /notation link in their Help center (eg, Astronomy).

Comment: This is better than the answers I found on the Math.SE meta.  Nice job with the examples.