# The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, mathjax

When editing a post on a site where MathJax is enabled there in "how to format" there is a link [Mathjax help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) which points to a page not as useful as the [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on http://meta.math.stackexchange.com.

So I suggest to replace that link with [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The [Quantum Computing Meta - MathJax Tutorial](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/278) offers a greater set of instructions than what is offered in Math's Tutorial. In addition there are links at the bottom of the answer listing some particularly helpful sites, including instructions and examples for every compatible MathJax feature.

Comment: Related: [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/335251) – You can compare the list in Shog9's answer here to the list in the linked question, if you want to identify the sites with MathJax enabled where it *hasn't* been customized.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, here's how this works:

- https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/ is the default guide for all sites that have MathJax enabled. It's pretty generic, and that's a good thing.
- Any site with MathJax enabled can request that a *different* guide be used for this purpose. Ideally, they'll write one specific to the needs of their community, but if they want to link to [Mathematics.SE's guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead, that's fine too - as long as they don't mind it being specific to Math's needs in some ways (and, obviously, controlled by folks with editing rights on Math's meta).

---

As of April 21, 2023, 14 sites (and their corresponding meta sites) have customized MathJax help links:

- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

  - Astronomy (same URL as Mathematics)
  - Computational Science (same as Mathematics)
  - History of Science and Mathematics (same as Mathematics)
  - Physics (same as Mathematics)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/using-mathjax-tex-on-the-cryptography-site)
- [Earth Science](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-format-math-and-chemistry-expressions-here)
- [Engineering](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/how-can-i-use-mathjax-latex-to-typeset-equations-on-this-site)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/game-development-mathjax-cookbook)
- [Operations Research](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/a-brief-guide-to-mathjax-for-pse-users)
- [Robotics](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-here-using-mathjax)
- [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation)

Any other site wishing to change theirs should post a feature request on their meta site (ideally *after* writing their own guide). If the community agrees on what URL their MathJax help link should point to, the site's moderators can add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the meta post to [escalate the request for staff attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca).

---

Note: as of March 13, 2019, this setting also affects the "Learn more: **MathJax help**" link shown on `/editing-help#latex`.

[image]

Comment: Should we (get somebody who knows about MathJax to) create a better SE-targeted page based on the popular meta posts, and then add that to the help center for sites using MathJax?  (Site-specific additions are possible; SO has the "how to write a minimum complete verifiable example" entry.)

Comment: If someone wanted to adapt these for a general audience, we could add it as a help-center page. I'd still want to allow for these per-site overrides in cases where a given site's usage is significantly different from the general case.

Comment: Yeah, not trying to force something down sites' throats if they have individual needs; it sounded like there was some unneeded duplication going on so I wanted to ask.  (I'm not a MathJax user myself.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Already exists: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation (at these two sites, at least)

Comment: Thx @Shog9 for the clarification. I think it might be useful if (maybe additionally to what Monica Cellio suggested) you could in the future amend your answer here with links to new Mathjax pages on SE.

Comment: @zaq oh, thanks.  I think Worldbuilding will want to get some of that.

Comment: Trivia: technically Mathematics is a special case in that it uses the custom page in a slightly different way than the rest... In practice, this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Harvard redesigned their site but they didn't port the texman url: [Can we get the MathJax reference link fixed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341346/can-we-get-the-mathjax-reference-link-fixed) and Google didn't index that new site yet (nor is their an on-site search) so I have no idea if it got a new place or was simply left out.