# Better MathJax reference on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, new-users, mathjax, editing-help

When asking questions on Math.SE, the "MathJax help »" link on the sidebar points to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which in my opinion is very friendly to users who have never heard about MathJax before.

However, on many other sites, the help link points to [something like a complete documentation](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/), which seems to be too complete for new users.

Due to its brevity and helpfulness, I think we should use [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as a crash course on all SE sites, maybe after immigrating this post to Meta Stack Exchange if necessary.

---

Actually, I've found [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246184/338645), but after nearly 2 years, it received 0 answers and even 0 comments. Also, that post consider this problem a "bug", but I think it should be a "feature request". This is why I'm posting my own question now.