# How to ask a mathematics question using the right symbols and operators?

Tags: support, mathjax, posting

I am not able to use some special symbols like for theta, alpha and all similar symbols. Also, how to get on with the exponent and fraction?

Comment: which site are you interested in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-a-more-specific-guide)

Comment: see also: [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/165773)

Comment: So far as I can see, this is not off-topic, because MathJax is part of the Stack Exchange network. The proposed duplicate seems like a stretch, and possibly unhelpful. I also don't see anything wrong with leaving it open. I vote to leave this question alone.

Comment: However, please edit your question to include details of where you are trying to use this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, check whether the site you're posting on actually supports MathJax: [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/295232)

There's a tutorial/reference guide on Mathematics Meta; there you will find *how* to produce the right symbols and formatting: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

If MathJax is not enabled on the site, you can simulate a fraction of it with HTML entities and Unicode. This very site does not have MathJax enabled, but writing `&alpha;` produces α, and `2<sup>3</sup>` produces 2<sup>3</sup>. Fractions don't work, but small fractions like 1/2 can be written in plain text as well.

Comment: Fractions (at least the common ones) do work: ½, ⅓, ¼, ⅔, ¾. (That's U+00BD, U+2153, U+00BC, U+2154, and U+00BE, respectively.) You can produce them in an editor and then copy and paste them, or you can use something like AutoHotkey for Windows that lets you map them to keystrokes.