# Can we get the MathJax reference link fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, help

The [MathJax reference](https://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) that is linked in the help box below a new answer is broken.

How can that be fixed?

Should electronics meta have a tutorial like the [math meta tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or perhaps link there instead?

[image]

---

This came from EE, but probably affects other sites, too.

Comment: Content available here: http://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288209/158100

Comment: Thanks @rene for linking to that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up! I've replaced the old URL with the one that rene identified - the default MathJax help links should now point to http://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

As rene also pointed out, [you may request that this be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-a-more-specific-guide/288209#288209) on a per-site basis if the folks on your site have taken the time to create custom guidance.

Comment: I'd posted about this problem on Astronomy Meta (thinking it was specific to Astronomy.SE). If @Shog9 would like to post this answer on https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/mathjax-help-link-is-broken to say the link is fixed, I'll click the tick and accept it there (with an upvote). Or is it more in keeping with SE etiquette if I just delete that question?

Comment: You can self-answer too, @astrid! Else, I'll post something a bit later.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9! I shan't self-answer, since as you're the one who resolved the problem I think the answer credit should be yours.