# Notify editors when a question that contains MathJax is migrated to a site with no MathJax support

Tags: feature-request, migration, notifications, mathjax

Sometimes questions from [sites which support MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/329351) (such as [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)) get migrated to the sites which don't support it (such as [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)). During this time, it's likely for the formatting of migrated posts to get completely messed up due to, say, a matrix that doesn't get rendered.

Users who can [edit posts without peer review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) on the sites which receive such questions should be notified when this happens.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37891398/1) ([got fixed later on](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37891398/2))

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250200)