# Is the dollar sign ($) used for markdown? If yes, then how can I safely insert it?

Tags: support, markdown

I want to write something basic like "10 $US" but sometimes it makes the text look weird. It changes the font and writes italic text. And sometimes it will insert a newline. For example in my [answer for this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/6833).

How can I safely insert a dollar sign?

Comment: For reference: [the list of MathJax-enabled sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607).  A couple of them use `\$` as formula delimiters, so on those sites the lone $ will render normally.  But on most, $ is a MathJax delimiter.

Comment: [**backslash**] [dollar sign]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Many Stack Exchange sites which involve a strong use of mathematics will have [MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) enabled for easily creating mathematical formulas. This script uses the dollar sign as a beginning and ending delimiter, so you will have to escape them like so: `\$`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any pointers where I can look? Yes I have MathJax and I use githubpages. It really messes up the content. So I use `$` every time but it looks ugly as hell.

Answer (score 5):

On a site where math mode is available by using a dollar sign—as well as on a site where math mode is not available—you can write a range of five to ten dollars by escaping each dollar sign with a backslash (`\$5-\$10`). You will see the symbols that you intended.

- Result on this site: $5-$10

However, on a site where math mode is available by using a dollar sign, if you don't use a backslash before each dollar sign (`$5-$10`), you see the sequence five, dash, one, zero. The five and the dash get formatted in math mode.

- Result on this site: $5-$10

Recall that, when expressing a numeric range, you may wish to use a typographic en dash, rather than a hyphen-minus character. One way to specify that is an XML-style character reference (`\$5&ndash;\$10`).

- Result on this site: $5–$10

On a site where math mode is available by using a dollar sign, by accidentally using the XML-style character reference in math mode `$5&ndash;$10`, you would produce *an error*.

- Result on this site: $5–$10

We can clarify what's happening, by investigating a little further. Spoiler: We won't find useful techniques in this direction.

Recall that, in math mode, there is an escape command (`\text{xyz}`). Escaped text in math mode will be formatted as text.

- Result on this site: $\text{xyz}$

Escaped text in math mode clearly has an appearance that is clearly different from formatting as mathematics, the formatting that occurs when the escape command is *not* used (`$xyz$`). When formatted as mathematics, letters display in italics. They are spaced differently from letters as text.

- Result on this site: $xyz$

Inside that escape command, neither LaTeX syntax for the en dash (`--`) nor XML-style syntax for the en dash (`&ndash;`) will be understood. If you try them (`$5\text{--7&ndash;}$10`), those constructs will be treated only as text character data inside math mode.

- Result on this site: $5\text{--7–}$10

Comment: The simplest way to write an en-dash is to just include it directly as a Unicode character without any encoding. This works even inside MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

In markdown editors such as `GitHub`, or `Jupyter notebook`, with `MathJax` available, you can use **double backslash and a dollar sign together** to show any amount or range of amount in the dollar.

Note that, in `StackExchange` or any `StackOverflow` related site, a single backslash is enough. So I couldn't show you the double backslash, because this editor refuse to show double backslash together.

Comment: FYI, to show a literal double backslash in a Stack answer, persist -- use four backslashes to get two: \\\\. ("Comments" work differently than "Answers", however!)

Answer (score 0):

`$` - code insertion worked for me in something like MathJax. Just \$ was printed as is.

Comment: The source of the [now-fixed] linked answer shows that just \$ works perfectly.

Comment: I just suggested the one method that suits me. Maybe someone will work on the same system, which works weirdly with \ $, as in my situation

Comment: Well that worked for me. My markdown linter was escaping my dollar signs in an auto-save feature in some situations (maybe one's it thought were part of an equation? I couldn't really get rhyme or reason) and then my markdown to html converting was treating the slash as simply text, which I think it should have. So I was stuck (short of figuring out my auto-save issue). Wrapping it in code markings was just the trick I needed for this. Cheers.