# Markdown shorthand for Stack Exchange sites in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, magic-links

I know that most (if not all) SE sites have a shorthand link in comments. For example, [SO] for Stack Overflow, [Math.SE] for math.stackexchange.com, and [SoftwareEngineering.SE] for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Apparently these are not supported in questions and answers. Is there any plan to add this feature or is it intended only for comments?

Comment: Why would you need this except on metas? And except on MSE itself, why would you need it often enough even there for it to be worth adding?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I encountered a situation where I wanted to add a link to Software Engineering from an answer on SO. You are right that this occurs very rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that should be implemented *everywhere* because it's unnecessary.

#### However, implementing it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) will be *very* useful as linking to other SE sites are more often here, even more than in comments on other sites.

Comment: I don't see the harm in enabling them network wide. It's already difficult enough to memorize each community's site-specific formatting quirks. ([Internal Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297972/351462),[YouTube embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/351462), [MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/351462), etc)

Answer (score 1):

#### I do not think this comes up enough to be an issue

I *never* see another exchange linked in a *non-meta* question or answer. At least, not properly. Directing users to other exchange sites for more clarity should be done via *comments*, and as such, does not benefit from shorthand in the actual question/answer box.

It is important to note that I *do* see links to *questions* in other Stack Exchange sites, either to show prior research, or suggest further reading. These links would still need to include the full link, in order to direct users to the correct question, and thus would not benefit from a "shorthand" to the main site page.