# Why does half of my question not show in the preview?

Tags: support, markdown, posting

When I post, half of my question isn't shown. Why is this?

[image: Screenshot of the post editor]

Comment: Try posting the same thin when going to the site in https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<` can be interpreted as the beginning of an HTML tag. You have two options to avoid this:

- use `&lt;` instead, so that the parser knows your not starting an HTML tag
- use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) if that's [enabled on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/295232), like this: `$0<y<=1$`, or even better: `$0<y \le 1$`. As a bonus, this will nicely format your question like a scientific paper:

[image]

Comment: could also stuff the mathy bits inside backticks.

Comment: You beat me to the "post" button again.  We've got to stop doing this. :-)