# Weird behaviour when using two (2) $ signs?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax

Over at Worldbuilding I posted [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/124946/32789) and included:

```
* Build a $1 Billion home ([Mukesh Ambani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilia_(building)))
* Build a $1.2 Billion Yacht ([Roman Abramovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(yacht)))
```

and that came out as:
[image]
whereas here it comes out just fine:

- Build a $1 Billion home ([Mukesh Ambani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilia_(building)))
- Build a $1.2 Billion Yacht ([Roman Abramovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(yacht)))

I got around that by using `USD` instead of `$` and tested on Ask Ubuntu, Cooking and it seems to be limited to Worldbuilding, but obviously, I don't have an account everywhere...

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ: Thanks for the edit!  **:-)** Forgot about that!

Comment: Also note that this is the wrong syntax for American dollars: the correct syntax is "$1.2 billion".

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Thanks!  Editing both here and there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That site has MathJax enabled so dollar signs are considered as delimiters of math blocks.

See List Item 38 of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/350567).

Use `\$` if you want a literal dollar sign instead of denoting a math block.

Comment: Ah, Sorry to have asked a dumb question and thanks for the answer.  I can only accept in 11 minutes. **+1** already and my answer edited in the mean time as well.  **:-)**