# How to write math with LaTeX?

Tags: support, latex

According to the tutorials, you're supposed to use $ to indicate LaTeX math, but the syntax is never mentioned anywhere.

Writing
$$
...math...
$$
 doesn't do anything, and neither does writing $\frac{1}{2}$. So how do you write math using LaTeX?

**Note:**
I do think "The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide", but that's not what I am asking here, I'm asking wether the format above is correct, and if not, what have I done wrong, because writing LaTeX on Mathematics Stack Exchange didn't work for me.

EDIT:
After a couple of days LaTeX *did* eventually work for me, apparently, for some reason, my browser refused to show code at first. If possible, please do close this post.

Comment: Which site are you trying to write math on? Are you sure it's one of the sites with the feature enabled?

Comment: Im trying to write math on the mathematics site of StackExchange. Im pretty sure it is enabled there..

Comment: What do you mean by *"indice LaTeX math"*?

Comment: Yeah, thats the website i looked at, they never tell the direct syntax, only that you have to use $ or $$, but it still wont work for me. @PeterMortensen

Comment: Mathjax only works on certain sites. Meta Stack Exchange isn't one of them. Unfortunately I don't think there are any sandboxes that a new user can use to experiment (Math's [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370) is on its meta and thus requires 5 rep). Does MathJax work at all for you (e.g. in existing posts on the Math site)?

Comment: @Laurel MathOverflow Meta only requires 1 rep for meta participation; maybe one can set up a sandbox there?

Comment: @Sonic They already have one [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/55).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [not all sites support MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/295232), so it won't work here on Meta Stack Exchange.

Depending on your Internet connection, rendering MathJax may take a long time, especially in the post preview, but also sometimes on the main pages. There's also a chance that your browser or provider is blocking the JavaScript needed to render the math (but then it shouldn't work for other users' posts either).

There's no privilege involved for using MathJax (unlike for e.g. posting images on some sites). If you're decent at LaTeX and the preview doesn't work well enough, just submit your post; it might load faster and you can edit your post if the result is wrong. Also, other users on the site will probably help correct the formatting if needed.