# Misleading text in editing help on sites where MathJax is delimited with \$

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, mathjax

Credits to Electrical Engineering user @MarcusMüller who reported it here: [Help page about embedding LaTeX is wrong, needs fixin'](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7208/113522), but it's an issue on more sites:

- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)
- [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)

These sites, unlike other network sites which use MathJax (note that [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/295232) may not be completely accurate), use `\$` to delimit MathJax blocks instead of `$`, but the Help Center says:

> You can use single dollar signs to delimit inline equations

and

> ```
> The equation $3x^2 + 5x +1 = 0$ has the solutions
> ```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this forward.

Comment: Yikes! Would it be better to fix those sites so that plain `$` works? Do those sites use `$$`, or `\$\$` (or some other combination) for non-inline MathJax?

Comment: @PM2Ring just `$$` works. `\$` is often chosen if MathJax is added late in the site lifecycle, and there are many posts which use $ for its original purpose (monetary amounts).

Comment: Game Development also uses `\$` delimiters, but due to a bug in the snippet that generates the list, it doesn't show it. (I've [asked its author to update it](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8401110#8401110).)

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. It'd be painful to fix old posts with $ used for money. And painful to convert `\$` to `$`. OTOH, we did have the massive conversion across the network of `http` to `https`...

Comment: This bit me in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50277 - I actually *assumed* it was `$` at first, and when it didn't seem to work checked the formatting help. Since it also said `$`, I supposed maybe it was wonky just for me, or at the moment. Because of my initial assumption, I'm +1 on the better fix being to make it so that the help page is correct, and matched `$` do mean inline latex; escape them if you want monies - as Marcus said in the EE Meta post, 'we're dealing with far more math than finances'

Answer (score 3):

That's my bad. I overlooked the custom delimiter handling when updating the example formula on that page.

The fix is in the queue and will be deployed shortly. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Are there any sites other than the four listed in the question which use `\$` delimiters for MathJax?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Code Golf.