# MathJax rendering bug with escaped dollar sign (\$), apparently only on crypto.SE

Tags: bug, markdown, mathjax, site-specific

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Offending Markdown:** (see also live [in this post revision on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/86376/3))

```
> $$\left|\Pr_{k\leftarrow_\$\ \{0,1\}^n}[\mathcal{A}(1^n, F(k,-))=1] - \Pr_{f\leftarrow_\$\ \{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n}[\mathcal{A}(1^n, f(-))=1]\right|\leq \mathrm{negl}(n).$$
```

Apparently, it only happens on crypto.SE. I could neither reproduce it on meta.crypto.SE ([link [deleted post]](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1469/12589)) nor in math.SE's formatting sandbox ([trial 1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32785/85341), [trial 2 [deleted post]](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32786/85341)).

I didn't want to spam crypto.SE and hence couldn't narrow down the offending Markdown.

Comment: One may want to note that it has not been confirmed to _only_ happen on [crypto.se]. We just couldn't reproduce it on either [crypto.meta.se] nor [math.meta.se].

Comment: Why do you think it’s a bug? The snippet actually shows `\\\$` rather than `\$`. That’s indeed invalid MathJax code.

Comment: Oh, I see: the Markdown source seems to only include a single backslash. So the Markdown translator apparently incorrectly trippled the backslash in the resulting HTML (and MathJax is not to blame). That’s weird.

Comment: Some sites use `\$` to delimit MathJax blocks instead of `$`: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348676/282094 - and they're not sure if that's a complete list.