# Rendering bug with backslash and dollar sign on MathJax-enabled sites

Tags: bug, code-formatting, mathjax

Typing

```
`\$`
```

on a MathJax-enabled site renders

`\\\$`

instead of the expected

`\$`

On the preview, the rendering is also wrong, but it only renders `\\$`, as can be seen in the following screenshot:
[image: I typed \$ on Puzzling Meta, and the preview showed \$]

This happens also on Math Meta, and breaks item 15 of their very popular [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/495620).

[This recent bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356953/643262) might also be caused by this, although what I report here is not limited to Crypto.SE.

Comment: [Also reported on Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1#comment148310_5020)

Comment: Different manifestation of this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358098 .

Comment: @Emil: yes, exactly the same issue.

Comment: Also reported at https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/code-blocks-add-extra-backslash-if-followed-by-a-dollar-sign, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/typesetting-dollars-in-equations .

Comment: The problem also has consequences in MathJax expressions starting and ending with `$$`(but apparently not those starting and ending with `$`); see [this closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369908/184379).