# The $ sign introduced with \ wreaks havoc the MathJax rendering

Tags: bug, mathjax

On a MathJax-enabled website, it's supposed to be possible to enter a LaTeX $ as `\$`, but it does not work consistently inside a formula delimited by `$$` at start and end. For example, on crypto-SE or crypto.meta-SE this:

```
$$
k\;\overset{ *}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{\$}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{ +}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
$$
```

renders in the final post as (see [test post](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1548/555)).

[image: What I see]

Also, right-click "*Show Math as...* Tex Commands" gets it wrong:

[image: Show Math as.. Tex Commands]

All this is independent of browser and math mode. The preview while composing an answer is all right, which only makes things harder! Using `\mathdollar` or `\textdollar` does not work.

The issue does not occur inside a formula delimited by single `$` at start and end; and "*Show Math as..* Tex Commands" does the Right Thing.

---

The issue may have a common cause, but is significantly different form the one reported at [Rendering bug with backslash and dollar sign on MathJax-enabled sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357702/rendering-bug-with-backslash-and-dollar-sign-on-mathjax-enabled-sites), which in a nutshell is that it's shown `\\\$` (and `\\$` in the preview) when on a MathJax-enabled website it's rendered (from the default state of markup) the four source characters

```
`\$`
```

The issue is very similar to [Weird line break in LaTeX formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358098/weird-line-break-in-latex-formula), but is better characterized.

The issue is also similar to [MathJax rendering bug with escaped dollar sign (\$), apparently only on crypto.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356953/mathjax-rendering-bug-with-escaped-dollar-sign-apparently-only-on-crypto-s) (which has the extra complexity that it reportedly occurs only on *some* MathJax-enabled websites).

And now the present question distinguishes three different environments that occur in the rendering of the sequence of two source characters `\$` on a MathJax-enabled website, with two environments triggering some (different) behavior.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there were other bug reports related to MathJax where the culprit was that that `\ ` gets tripled in mysterious ways, but I can’t find it now.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek found it.

Comment: @Luuklag Thank you. @fgrieu Btw, the correct names of the commands are `\mathdollar` and `\textdollar`, not “dollard”. (But they do not work anyway.)

Comment: Concerning the edit: the bug eventually manifests differently because the expression appears in a different context, but it is the same issue: you type `\$`, and the SE parser silently replaces it with `\\\$`. You can clearly see that in your screenshot with “Show Math as TeX commands”, or just look at the HTML source of the page. Then, MathJax duly renderes the extra \\ as a new line in the alignment.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: and that occurs, or not/differently, depending if in preview or not, and the parity of the number of consecutive `$` sign(s) introducing the `\$`sequence. Oh my.