# Markdown renderer changes indentation inside fenced code blocks

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, commonmark

On some (but not all!) sites, code fenced blocks (but not indented code blocks!) are indented incorrectly. The following Markdown input:

> ````
> ```
>
> for arg; do
>     if [[ $arg ]]; then
>         echo "$arg"
>     done
> done
> ```
> ````

Gets displayed as

> ```
> for arg; do
>     if [[ $arg ]]; then
>     echo "$arg"
>     done
> done
> ```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the buggy render]

This is true both for the live preview and for the persistent rendering. The following features are required to be present to trigger this bug:

- Fenced code block

  - It doesn’t matter whether a language is specified after the starting fence
  - It doesn’t matter how long the fence is (e.g. ````` ```` ````` also works).
- Empty line inside code block — doesn’t have to be the first line, and can indeed be before or *after* the wrongly indented line
- Two lines containing `$`

  - Removing either of the `$`s above “fixes” the indentation
  - Adding a second `$` to the first line that contains `$` “fixes” the indentation
  - Adding a second `$` to the *second* line that contains `$` does *not* fix the indentation
  - The `$` can be anywhere in the line, it doesn’t have to be the first character of a variable

Furthermore, if the closing code fence isn’t followed by any more content (including newline), then the closing code fence is *also displayed* (but only in combination with the features listed above).

#### Verified on

(More or less randomly sampled)

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/
- https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ ([real-life example](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/14679/29))
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/
- https://biology.stackexchange.com/
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/
- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

( = broken,  = works)

Comment: Could this be related to [sites with MathJax enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/388442)?

Comment: Code Review breaks using `\$` or `$$` instead of `$`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVM1G.png

Comment: … I’m puzzled why anybody would downvote this.