# How one can achieve that in the Stack Exchange questions/answers one types Greek letters, other symbols and symbols with subscripts?

Tags: discussion, site-specific-formatting

I am active in the [Mathematica Stack Exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). I would like to be able to use Greek letters in my questions and answers instead of something like `\[Omega]`.

I already asked this question several years ago. I received an answer that one has to install the [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) add-on. I did it on two different computers. On one it worked perfectly, on the other it did not at all.

Several years passed, and I put out this question again. Something may have happened since.

So, how should I operate best of all?

As much as I understand, [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is not the solution. I am not asking about a redactor to type formulas in browsers. In contrast, I am looking for the possibility to copy-paste the plain Mathematica code containing the Greek letters from my Mathematica notebook into the window where one types-in the Stack Exchange answers (see the image below). Later this code anyone should be able to copy-paste into his/her own notebook and it will work as a Mathematica code. The expression for the letter alpha like this $\alpha$ is not the solution, since the Mathematica code for alpha is slash[Alpha]. I know that there is a way to enter in this window slash[Alpha], but get it visible as the Greek letter. I am asking about such a possibility.

[image]

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax that site supports MathJax or is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: @ mdewey Thank you, but no, the MathJa seems not to be the solution for me. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: It appears you fail to understand the concept of MathJax. You can simply type in that box for example $\alpha$ to render a greek alpha.

Comment: An overview of supported symbols can be found here: http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/symbols/welcome.html

Comment: Please see a further edit.

Comment: After it is finally clear what this question is about I'm voting to re-open.