# Chemistry equation \ce modifier works in a non chem SE site's posts, but not in search results. Should we consider it "working" and start using it?

Tags: support, search, markdown, mathjax

In [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) there are a lot of questions related to chemistry (mostly production and combustion of rocket propellants and air/water for people) and after six years there I just this moment discovered that the following (from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5353/12102)) renders correctly there (and doesn't here):

`$\require{mhchem}\ce{H_2O -> H+ + OH-}$ and then $\ce{2OH- -> O- + H_2O}$`

$\require{mhchem}\ce{H_2O -> H+ + OH-}$ and then $\ce{2OH- -> O- + H_2O}$

And while it is still readable, it doesn't render perfectly when post excerpts are displayed in search results, which is a secondary question.

Should we consider the chemistry equation \ce modifier to be working and supported in Space SE and start using it?

> [image: chemistry \ce renders correctly in Space Exploration SE posts]
>
> ---
>
> [image: chemistry \ce does not render correctly in Space Exploration SE search results]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not the foremost expert on this, but my understanding of MathJax is as such:

1. It's entirely not loaded on some sites. This includes Meta Stack Exchange, which is why 'normal' maths such as `$1 + 1 = 2$` doesn't even work here.
2. Wherever MathJax is available, you can load functionality from any package you like using `$\require{package}$`. This is explained in more detail at [the MathJax 2.7 documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions).
3. On the sites where it is loaded, MathJax can be optionally configured to automatically load set of packages. On Chemistry, this includes `mhchem`. So you can directly write `$\ce{H2O}$` without needing to further load `mhchem`.

So, there is no case in which you can use MathJax but cannot use `mhchem`. The only thing that's different is whether MathJax is configured to load `mhchem` from the start. This is the case on Chemistry, so you don't have to explicitly do `$\require{mhchem}$`. It's not the case on other sites, including Physics, and Space Exploration as you wrote. However, `mhchem` will work on all those sites as long as you `require` it.

I'd therefore argue that `mhchem` *has always worked* on the latter sites, just that it was a bit hidden. :-)

(There are also many other packages which must be explicitly loaded on Chemistry: see e.g. [What additional formatting features are available to MathJax (possibly via \require{})?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/16683.))

Comment: Related: [full list of sites supporting MathJax, with those supporting mhchem specifically annotated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

Comment: As long as I've been "in space" people have used all kinds of notations: `H2O`, `H<sub>2</sub>O`, `H₂O`, `$H_2O$` but it turns out we've had the solution all along! Like Dorothy in the Wizard of Oz, we've had our ruby slippers and simply needed to tap our heels together three times and say "[\require{mhchem}... \require{mhchem}... \require{mhchem}...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPs2Y4FdGzM)"