# Are there plans to switch to the current version of MathJax?

Tags: discussion, support, status-review, stack-exchange, mathjax

As [pointed out on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35316), Stack Exchange still uses MathJax v2, although v4 was released recently. (The [answer by Davide Cervone](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/mathjax-out-of-date/35383#35383) - one of the MathJax developers - summarized some potential problems when moving from v2 to v3 or v4.)

- Are there plans to switch to a newer version of MathJax on Stack Exchange [sites which use MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606)?
- If yes, is there some kind of estimate *when* this could happen?

I am asking partly because some of the MathJax-related bugs which are reported on various per-site-metas would probably be resolved by this switch. For example, recently I saw this post where the answer was that this would not be a problem with MathJax v3 or v4: [Double overline renders poorly, except in MathML](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5536).

If there are plans to switch to a newer version *soon*, it would probably make sense to wait with reporting (or resolving) various MathJax-related bugs after that date.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, in fact that post is linked in my question, right at the beggining.  Still, this is a network-wide issue - so I considered it worth posting here. Moreover, it is slightly different. (This question asks whether SE plans to use the newer version of MathJax. Another minor difference is that the post on [math.meta.se] was made about a month or two before releasing v4. There was an older question about v3: [Switch to MathJax version 3?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30901)) At the same time, I will definitely understand if some people see this as redundant.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I missed that you had already linked to the Math Meta post. I was mostly just linking it for convenience (and because that post had already been escalated to staff). :)