# Is it possible to add a "Copy to clipboard" option in the MathJax drop-down list?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

In [Piazza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piazza_(web_service)), when viewing the source of some math that is typeset using MathJax, there is the option to "Copy to clipboard", as shown in the screenshot below. If I click on "TeX Commands", then all the code associated with the math is automatically copied to clipboard, and I can click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> anywhere else to paste the code. I've not found this option when right-clicking on math that is typeset on different SE sites, such as math.SE or stats.SE, I only see the "Show Math As" option. I often want to copy and paste the TeX commands for a math snippet, but to do so, I have to

1. Click on "Show Math As".
2. Click on "Tex Commands".
3. Highlight the code in the window that pops up.
4. Click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
5. Click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to wherever I want to paste it.

Implementing the "Copy to clipboard" option here on SE would save me from having to complete steps 1-4 every time. Would this be possible?

[image]

Comment: In the meantime, it might be easier to go to "edit" the post, so you can copy the code from there.

Comment: The "copy to clipboard" option is new in v3 of MathJax.  The StackExchange sites are still using v2.7.5.  Because v3 has an updated API, changing to v3 would take some work, but they could update to 2.7.9 (the highest v2 version) without trouble, but it would still not give you the copy menu item.

Comment: @DavideCervone thanks for the info! Would you happen to know of the timeline for switching to v3? If at all?

Comment: Nevermind, found a relevant question: [Are there plans to switch to the current version of MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385913/941682)