Workaround for bug causing \ before dollar signs to be rendered as \\\ on MathJax enabled sites?
As the title says, a single \ in a code block is being rendered as \\\ if preceding a $. This seems to be the same bug reported here, but since it hasn't been fixed, I am asking for a workaround. Apparently, on sites with MathJax enabled, we cannot write \$,  which renders my answer here useless. I need to give an awk command which includes a literal \$, the \ is essential and without it the code doesn't work. Sadly, this is rendered as \\\$ which also doesn't work. And it is particularly confusing since the preview shows \\$, already wrong, but the final rendered code shows \\\$ which is even more wrong.
Is there a way around this? How could I get my answer to show
'/^[^#]/{\$5-=5}{\$4+=5}1'

and not
'/^[^#]/{\\\$5-=5}{\\\$4+=5}1'

Is there perhaps a way of deactivating MathJax for the specific code block? Is the only solution to deactivate MathJax for the entire site?

FWIW, EE.SE has MathJax enabled, but doesn't seem to be affected by this bug. Preview: https://i.sstatic.net/Qsu2IRVn.png, Posted: https://i.sstatic.net/yrhmEcB0.png

@Velvet huh, then maybe there is a solution! I tried your exact same example on Bioinformatics, and the preview showed \\$ for \$ and after posting it became \\\$.

EE.SE has a MathJax setup different from most other sites, in that it uses \$ rather than plain $ as a delimiter (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607).
